# Accessing elements in a Hash Table

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, hashtable

I'm going in circles and confused as how to access my elements in this hash table.  I have returned my data from json successfully. Its an object but this object contains two columns fips and the corresponding value.  I want to access the first row.  I've tried using raw.fips / raw[fips] and raw[0] all returned undefined but there is data in raw I just don't know to access it.

here is the ajax if it helps

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: WebRoot + "ws/GIS.asmx/CensusData",
    data: d,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        fipsData = data.d;                                            
        console.log("json object returned data : " + fipsData);
        init(regType, varId);                
    } //ends success function
});  //ends ajax call
```

The ajax returns data and in the log there is 3141 rows / elements I'm not sure.

```
var raw = fipsData;
var valMin = Infinity;
var valMax = -Infinity;        

for (var index in raw) {
    fipsCode = raw[fips];
    console.log(fipsCode);
}

//log data
console.log("fipsData is : " + fipsData);              
console.log("Raw number :" + raw);//undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong index in this code:

```
for (var index in raw) {
    fipsCode = raw[fips];
    console.log(fipsCode);
}
```

You've set `index` as the variable that you are using for the loop, but you are using `fips` when you try to access it.  Try changing `fipsCode = raw[fips];` to `fipsCode = raw[index];`.

Also, you should always to a `hasOwnProperty` check when you are looping through an object, to avoid attempting to process methods and such.  Try this:

```
for (var index in raw) {
    if (raw.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        fipsCode = raw[index];
        console.log(fipsCode);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work then, if you can show a sample of some of your returned data, that would make it easier to keep troubleshooting.

Comment: nailed it thanks.  I have to read up more on hash tables vs array's thats still not clicking for me just yet.  THANKS

Comment: No problem . . . happy to help.   :)   Check out this article on JS Objects vs. Arrays, it covers most of the basics:  http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Javascript_Object_and_Array.html